# in Dart, how to write a getters and setters for a Map[key]?

Tags: class, dart, getter

creating `getter`s and `setter`s for scalars is pretty easy, but cannot figure out how to set a `setter` for a `Map`:

```
// for scalar
String _str = 'hello';
String get str => _str;
String set str(val) => _str = val;

// for Map
Map _map = {};
Map get map[key] => _map[key]; <== Error: function body ...
Map set map[key](val) => _map[key] = val; <=== Error: '(' expected
```

seems the `operator[]` is called for, but that's is set at `class` level

note: the problem with

```
Map get map => _map
```

is that this allows you to change `_map` without going through a `setter`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I follow exactly what you are trying to do. It sounds like you want a top level Map variable, and be able to provide your own implementation for the [], and []= operators.

You have to create a class to override the operators [], and []=. However you can still achieve what (I think?) you are asking for. Off the top of my head, that would look something like this.

```
Map _map = new MyMap();

Map get map =>  _map;

set map(Map m) {
    _map = new MyMap.from(m);
}

class MyMap<K,V> implements Map {
    MyMap.from(Map<K, V> other) => ...;
    V operator [](K key) => ...;
    operator []=(K key, V value) => ...;
    ... other members
}
```